# Are weak - strong relations a valid consideration when writing harmony for a given soprano line?

Tags: voice-leading

When writing chord progressions for a given soprano line my textbook says that rhythmic considerations will often determine whether one harmony is better or less good than another. Think of a soprano line ^3^2^7^1. You might harmonize it with I V V I or with I ii6 V I. If the ^2 ^7 is in a weak-strong relation however only the second possibility is good. Repeating dominant Harmony will contradict the meter.

Can anyone else tell me if they agree with this? Why does ^7 have to fall on the strong beat and not ^2?

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine how the strong or weak position would make a difference, and much of that is having trouble imagining how that four-note cadence might fit into a meter one way or the other.  Do you have examples you could add?

Answer (score 1):

While you can harmonize ^3^2^7^1 as both I-V-V-I and I-ii6-V-I and still fit common practice period harmony, using I-V-V-I in any rhythm where the beat ^2 is on is weaker than the beat ^7 is on **makes the harmonic rhythm syncopated**, which is often not preferred in classical music.

Comment: why? They are both part of V and they are both active tones...

Comment: It's more that I tried imagining a 4-voice chorale measure with Beats 1-4 as ^3^2^7^1, then tried imagining that harmonized with Beats 1-4 as I-V-V-I, and was then struck at how abnormal that sounded.